# How do I view the challenges "listed below"?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

While skimming through the banner backgrounds I haven't unlocked but would like to, I came across some that told me to complete a list of challenges. The game says to see the challenges "listed below," however, nothing I have done (I tried all of the buttons on my PS4 controller, but to no avail) has let me actually *view* these challenges.

[image: see challenges below]

My fear is that this UI was designed for PC and was not kept in mind when it was ported to consoles, but I could be wrong. Is there a way to view these lists of challenges in-game, or am I forced to look online to see what they are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a bit misleading, yes. The challenges are listed elsewhere in the profile. Press start, and "challenges" is listed below options. Find the relevant challenge, and the tasks you have to accomplish will be listed below.

Comment: That's extremely counter-intuitive... is there a way to search in that menu? There are a LOT of challenges to sift through.

Comment: There is not, no.